# The time affects both textview android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, android-calendar

I have a question.I have two textview for put a start time and finish time.These connect to Calendar class with intent and get date. When I try to take start time I can take but its put date both textview .How can I seperate this ?

```
                 TextView bastarihi,bittarihi;
                 String year,month,day,year1,month1,day1;
                 String a="a";
                 private TextView clickedTextview;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_izin);
    bastarihi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bastarihi);
    bittarihi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bitistarihi);
        bastarihi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        clickedTextview=(TextView)v;
        Intent intent=new Intent(IzinActivity.this,Calendarr.class);
        intent.putExtra("a",a);
        startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    year=intent1.getStringExtra("year");
    month = intent1.getStringExtra("month");
    day = intent1.getStringExtra("day");

    if (clickedTextview != null)
        clickedTextview.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day );

    bittarihi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        clickedTextview = (TextView) view;
            Intent intent=new Intent(IzinActivity.this,Calendarr.class);
            intent.putExtra("a",a);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    year1=intent2.getStringExtra("year");
    month1 = intent2.getStringExtra("month");
    day1 = intent2.getStringExtra("day");
    if (clickedTextview != null)
        clickedTextview.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day );
    CallBack callBack1 = new CallBack() {
```

Comment: what is the use of intent2 if you are not utilizing it anywhere

Comment: This is my fault.I fix it.

Comment: Please indent you code properly. Your IDE/studio can do that for you. As it stands it’s too hard to read, I am not going to try.

Comment: Thank you I solved with onActivityResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same intent in `intent2`, try to move your code in `OnClickListener` . Maybe you should take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result . You could use `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent)` for receiving the date from your `Calendarr` class. Hope it helps!